# How do you program a button to successfully load the next data in an array

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have created a button, so that, when pressed it will load the next link in the array, but the only problem is that it doesn't update the view pager container. I have created a button for both `next` and `previous`, but I feel like I am missing a small detail, because this method does not load data into the viewerpager

Here is the code;

```
        lstData = new ArrayList<>();
        getData();

        ViewPager myrv = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_page);
        myViewPager = new PageViewAdapter(this, lstData);
        myrv.setAdapter(myViewPager);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (int_of_inital_chapter - 1 < 0) {
                    Log.d("Newest Data Present","YUH");
                } else {
                    URL = list.get(int_of_inital_chapter - 1).getLink();
                    lstData = new ArrayList<>();
                    getData();
                }

            }
        });

        previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (int_of_inital_chapter + 1 > list.size()) {
                    Log.d("Oldest Chapter Enabled","YUH");
                } else {
                    URL = list.get(int_of_inital_chapter + 1).getLink();
                    lstData = new ArrayList<>();
                    getData();
                }
            }
        });
```

PageViewAdapter Contructor

```
 public PageViewAdapter(Context context, List<Page> PageList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.PageList = PageList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
```

The algorithm works so that when the activity is created it automatically loads the data assigned to the inputted URL. Which Works. But I want to have the buttons load whatever is next or before the URL in the list array. What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly is the problem then? I mean how do the two buttons work now, are they loading any data or not?

Comment: They are not. I will update the post.

Comment: where is the getData() method?

Comment: I didn't think it was important to add it to the code, because its too long and the goal is that with the inputted URL, it returns a lstData which is then loaded into the viewPager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

declare the following globally:

```
private ViewPager myrv;
private ViewPagerAdapter myViewPager;
```

and then initialize them:

```
myrv = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_page);
myViewPager = new PageViewAdapter(this, lstData);
```

and also put the following in the buttons onClick

```
myViewPager = new PageViewAdapter(this, lstData); 
myrv.setAdapter(myViewPager);
```

Comment: When implementing the value `this` is different for both onClick and onCreate. In PageViewAdapter (which I posted the contructor is in the main thread), but the value `this` is different.

Comment: use getApplicationContext(); or Youractivity.this

Comment: So both work, but it looks like that my logic for finding the next link is faulted but nevertheless thank you so much!